# NoMethodError in TransactionsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add the sum of all the prices of a transaction of a current user,

I have this in my transaction controller

```
@group_transaction_id = @transactions.group_by(&:user_to_id).sum(&:price)
```

and this in my view

```
<%= @group_transaction_id[current_user.id] %>
```

but it throws `NoMethodError in TransactionsController#index`

[image]

whenever I remove .sum(&:price), it shows this on the browser

[image]

I want to calculate the total price of what is showing.

Comment: Try using `sum(:price)`

Answer (score 0):

Since `group_by` converts the records into hash, you can try something like this to calculate the sum of price:

```
@group_transaction_id = @transactions.group_by(&:user_to_id).map{|k,v| v.last[:price]}.sum
```

Comment: There is not producing the correct result, it is not giving me the sum of the hash in the image above, it is only returning.

Comment: You could play around and gets the sum from while doing **map** with the Hash. Maybe _v.last_  is not correct here, but similar approach could lead you to the sum.